# storing and retrieving json objects to / from a cookie

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

Im attempting to store json objects in a cookie, but im running into a few problems.
I can create my object like this:

```
product = {
   "name" : "prodname",
   "quantity" : 4
}
```

i then save this object in my cookie. As more products are added (its a shopping basket) i add further strings by appending new objects onto the end of the cookie string (so i essentially have lots of small seperate objects) . Im having trouble getting the objects back out of the cookie string though. Both `$.parseJSON` and `eval` fail when i attempt to read the objects back from the cookie. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hope you know that cookies have a very limited space. You probably should look at local storage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should probably be like:

```
{"products": [
    {
       "name" : "prodname",
       "quantity" : 4
    },
    {
       "name" : "prodname2",
       "quantity" : 3
    }
]}
```

The `[]` signifies an array.  When you want add another product, you load it from the cookie, update the array, then save it again.  If you wanted, you could skip the outer object and have the cookie just be the array.

EDIT: Say `cookieStr` is your cookie.

```
var root = $.parseJSON(cookieStr);
root.products.push(newProduct);
cookieStr = JSON.stringify(root);
```

Comment: how would i append new products to that string when more are added to the basket?

Comment: Why are you using `$.parseJSON()` instead of `JSON.parse()`? Is the jQuery version more robust?

Comment: @MikeCauser, yeah, the jQuery version (`$.parseJSON`) has better browser support.  Unfortunately, there is no equivalent in core jQuery for `JSON.stringify`.  So you end up having to use a shim anyway if you're supporting older browsers.

Answer (score 10):

its not a good practice to save the value that returned from JSON.stringify(cookieStr) to the cookie. it can lead to a bug in some browsers.

before using it you should convert it to base64 (using btoa), and when reading it, converting from base64 (using atob)

```
val = JSON.stringify(cookieStr)
val = btoa(val)

write_cookie(val)
```

Comment: A URL-encoded value also works well, and [can be used on IE < 10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: "it can lead to a bug in some browsers"  what bug? It would be helpful to have more context or a link to something that says what the bug is.

Comment: @MaxHeiber: per [RFC6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1), `"` is illegal in cookie value. I found a case where this breaks cookie parsing on server.